# Multiple Cached Tiles consumption

Tags: arcgis-server

I have created two caches for a project and there are coexisting within the same folder. 
[image: Cache]

Right behind I open ArcMap, add my File System Raster Layers and Share as Service.
My *.mxd document has exactly the name as the hosting file from my caches folder.
ArcGIS Server detect automatically the caches and I can publish the service.
But after that operation done within manager the cache seems to be not consume.
[image: Service]

Any idea how to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I found it !!

Consuming a pre-cache within the same folder must be (re)activated via ArcCatalog.

Go to your service, right click and select "Service Properties".
Dive to the "Caching" tab and reactivated "Using tiles from a cache"...